# Is there a definitive approach to a flicker-less scrolling parallax?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, parallax, flicker

Anyone that's ever worked on a scrolling parallax has run into some sort of flickering on one or more of the major browsers. And even if those issues are solved using some workaround, browser updates might still bring the flickering back.

What I want to know is whether someone has found a definitive solution or at least a recommended way of achieving the parallax effect without suffering from this.

I am aware fixed backgrounds and elements don't aren't affected, but in many occasions they're not an option.

I also did an extreme experiment once. I replaced the scrollbar with a custom one and then, instead of listening to a scroll event and then updating the elements styles, I would first update the elements and then set scrollTop, so when the scroll is rendered the object would already have its new style values. Not even that would stop the flickering on Chrome.

I am about to start another project featuring scrolling parallax effects and I'd really like to avoid having to deal with bug reports regarding flickering or having to tell the client they can't use the native scrollbar.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi cesarbie, I've found that keeping the parallax scrolling elements as simple as possible, and using efficient javascript creates a smooth parallax effect without flickering. I think that this is often a browser speed issue. Browsers have to calculate changes in the page, so fixed elements are easy to do whereas parallax scrolling elements require more calculations.

Comment: @David Why? Why would they force a render when I'm still updating stuff after the scroll event? What ever happened to web browsers? It's been like this for years now. I guess this is my last web project. I'm sick of this. I'm moving to native apps for devices, indefinitely or until webkit/blink (it's mostly them) put their sh*t together.